# How to refactor Java based base64 encoding to Python3?

Tags: java, python-3.x, base64

We have a Java code that creates passwords for MariaDB. Now we have a Python3 REST API which in some sort of way creates credentials for MariaDB too. The problem is that patterns after creation don't match. We should follow the Java code algorithm.

JAVA code:

```
private AccountInfo retriveAccountInfo(InetAddress addr, String login, String password, boolean autoCreateIfEnabled) {
    try {
        final var md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        final var raw = password.getBytes(UTF_8);
        final var hashBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest(raw));
...
```

exampleoutput : 'ALSenzd4DnVgfBW9Vdx+fvjxr+c='

How to achieve the same results using Python3 code?

Edit: the answer

```
import hashlib
import base64


password = 'test'
hashBase64 = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf8')).digest())
print(hashBase64)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256") maybe?

Comment: The result is too short for SHA256.  Based on the length of the result and the hash name used in the Java code, it will be SHA1.  So `hashBase64 = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf8')).digest())`.  But a simple hash of the plaintext is a poor choice for password hashing.  Consider adding a salt and performing repeated hashes per PBKDF2.  Switching to a stronger algorithm, like SHA 256, would be good too.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem!